# React JS rendering elements with on click function and passing index to on click function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to render React components using loop, Basically its link tag having on click function with value.

```
<p><a href="#" key={i} onClick={() => this.decreaseCount(i)} >delete</a></p>
```

where i is the index of the for loop. The problem is, instead of getting i's value inside this.decreaseCount(i) I am getting length of array. However I am getting correct index with key={i}

Need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work, try to use this (another way):

```
<p><a href="#" key={i} onClick={this.decreaseCount.bind(this,i)} >delete</a></p>
```

Check this example, you way will also work:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
   
   a(i){
     console.log(i);
   }
   
   render(){
     return (
        <div>
           {
               [1,2,3].map(i => <p onClick={ () => this.a(i)} > {i} </p>)
           }
        </div>
     )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Yeah, Working! Thanks for your help!